# Why does the object tag cut out the rest of my html?

Tags: html

I'm embeding an html file with my webpage via object tag ( ya that may be bad practice, but it works ). The problem being is that the object tag cuts off everything after it. I don't know why this is happening.

```
 <html>
 <header>
 </header>
 <body>
 <h1> This will show up </h1>
 <object type="text/html" data="myWebPage.html" />
 <h1> This won't show up </h1>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Why aren't you using an `<iframe>`?

Comment: I believe iframes are deprecated and advised against in best practices. Atleast this is what I am told.

Comment: You're thinking of [`<frame>`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/frame), not [`<iframe>`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`<object>` tags are non-void (not self-closing)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-object-element), so the browser is making a best guess at the correct HTML you intended, and arriving at this conclusion:

```
<object type="text/html" data="myWebPage.html">
    <h1> This won't show up </h1>
</object>
```

In this case the `<object>`'s content is the fallback – useful, for example, when you're trying to display a Flash video, but the browser doesn't have Flash.

Fix that by properly closing the tag:

```
<html>
<header>
</header>
<body>
<h1> This will show up </h1>
<object type="text/html" data="myWebPage.html"></object>
<h1> This won't show up </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Next time you see "strange" behavior like this, [run your code through a validator first](http://html5.validator.nu/) and it will often pick up obvious errors.

Answer (score 2):

I think the `<object>` tag should be have closing tag `</object>`
For detail: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp